# Relationship between dependant and independent variables

Tags: machine-learning, python, descriptive-statistics, probit

I'm completing an assignment that asked me to run some probit regression on some variables, and asked bunch of supporting questions. I am struggling to interpret one of them, it asks to "have a look at the relationship between dependant variable and independent variable #3". It also asks me to visualise that relationship, and recommend solutions based on it. Also, assessing the impact of it on the model's performance.

I have no idea what relationship could I analyse, that can be helpful in this case. Would you have any advices of how I can tackle it?

Comment: I'd recommend looking back over your notes. What topics have you covered so far in this course? Do any of them bear on examining the relationship(s) between 2 or more variables?

Comment: This course is running since October, I have covered in-depth many types of regression, but I cannot find anything about visualising relationships between dependant and independent variables..

Comment: Have you tried making a scatterplot of the data? Please add the [tag:self-study] tag to your post and read its wiki.